# Random walk on infinite ray

Tags: probability, random, random-walk

I need to describe some properties of the random walk on numbers $0, 1, 2, \cdots$. So, this process bounded on the left side and unbounded on the right. Transitions possible only to adjacent numbers, and for zero - left neighbour is zero itself. Probabilities of transition to the left and to the right equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

I need to calculate expectation of position if start position equals to $0$. 
I interested in both cases - expectation after $n$ steps and expectation after infinity steps.

Let me give you an example:
After 0 step: $0$ with prob $1.0$
After 1 step: $0$ with prob $0.5$, $1$ with prob $0.5$
After 2 steps: $0$ with prob $0.5$, $1$ with prob $0.25$, $2$ with prob $0.25$
etc.

Can you suggest some ideas, articles about this topic? Because I found many materials on the Internet about a random walk on infinity line, but none about a walk on an infinite ray.

Comment: The expectation will tend to infinity with $n$.

Comment: If $X_n$ is the position after $n$ steps then $E[X_n]=E[X_{n-1}]+\frac12 P(X_{n-1}=0)$

Comment: @Henry Yes, I believe that expectation tends to infinity. But I can't understand how to derive it from your equation, because if $P(X_{n - 1} = 0)$ tends to zero, then we can't say that expectation goes to infinity.

Comment: There is no bounding distribution and so the expectation is unbounded.  In fact $P(X_n=0)=\dfrac{n \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}{2^n} \le \dfrac12 \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}}$ for $n \ge 1$

Comment: If $X = (X_n)$ denotes your walk and $Y = (Y_n)$ denotes the simple random walk, then $X_n$ behaves very much like $|Y_n|$ because you can realize the distribution of $X_n$ by $$ \Bbb{P}(X_n = k) = \Bbb{P}(Y_n \in \{k, -k-1\} ), \qquad k \geq 0. $$

Comment: @Henry I think there is a typo in your inequality - should be $\ge$ instead of $\le$. Can you give me a hint - how you derive the combinatorial formula for this probability?) I can't understand, what meaning of $\binom{n}{\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I think you are wrong, because if I stand at zero and "try" go left, then I remain at zero position. So, if I have a sequence of moves "LLLLLR", then I stand at position 1, but the position in $Y_n$ will be $-4$. Or I misunderstand your idea.

Comment: You are correct about $\ge$ but I cannot now edit it.  $\binom{n}{\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor}$ is a central binomial coefficient: choose $n/2$ (rounded down) from $n$, and looks like $1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 20, 35, 70, 126, 252, \ldots$ approximately $\dfrac{2^n}{\sqrt{n \pi / 2}}$

Comment: It is like reflecting the ordinary SRW at $\frac{1}{2}$, or equivalently, you are identifying two states $k$ and $-k-1$ for SRW $Y$ to create $X$. So the moves $0\to0\to0\to0\to0\to0\to1$ for $X$ corresponds to moves $0 \to -1 \to 0 \to -1 \to 0 \to -1 \to -2$, and the state $-2$ is the same state as $1$ by our identification.